# SQL Database to XML?

Tags: sql-server, xml

I would like to export SQL data to an XML file so it can be read in COBOL. I am working with SQL Express 2008 r2.

Comment: I guess you have the COBOL part well covered since you are asking on *DBA* so you should probably start by looking at [XML Support in Microsoft SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345117%28v=sql.90%29.aspx?ppud=4) and [FOR XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx).

Comment: checked but do I have to write a query (using a FOR XML statement) to export the data from sql server 2008 r2 to a XML -doc?

Comment: Bear in mind this will also multiply the size of your DB.  Xml is flexible but extremely inefficient for storage.  When I export a table to XML normally it is 3-4 times the size of the data in SQL Server.

Comment: Btw Bert verleyen is the one that I asked the question for, so he knows it better than me :)

Comment: no, that was a friend ,he asked my question instead ,because it's the first time I 've seen and using this (forum) blog.

Answer (score 1):

I am using export data from query (table ) to XML in SQL when I have needs for autonomous transactions.

Way I do: I wrote a SQL-CLR stored procedure which using C# (code) and XML.Writer for writing data to disk

Here is parts of my code in C# (you need to compile this )

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System.IO;

public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
    public static void NapisiXMLtoFile(string fileName, SqlXml xmlLog )
    {
        try
        {
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(fileName);
            }
            File.WriteAllText(fileName, xmlLog.Value.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SqlContext.Pipe.Send("Error writing to file " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how you register your procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[clr_write_to_file]
    @fileName [nchar](100),
    @xmlLog [xml]
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
EXTERNAL NAME [WriteToFile].[UserDefinedFunctions].[NapisiXMLtoFile]
GO
```

and finally here is how you call your stored procedure to write file to disk

```
exec dbo.clr_write_to_file @imeFajla,@xmlLOG
```

Comment: Here is another useful link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k.aspx